# Не работает эмулятор в Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Вместо Android Studio 2 поставил 3-ю версию.
Теперь при запуске эмулятора получаю ошибки: http://joxi.ru/KAxNeDpT4gyWDm
Естесственно, эмулятор не запускается.
Как побороть их?
Операционка - Debian 8.

Answer (score 0):

Было что-то похожее после перехода со второй студии на третью, но у меня win10(64bit), перед обновлением студия предупредила что на 32-битных системах работать не будет. После обновления эмулятор падал со всевозможными кодами ошибок. После очередного падения попросил отправить краш-репорт разработчикам, я согласился. Через несколько дней студия попросила обновиться, после обновления эмулятор работал.

Comment: обновил Debian, ситуация не поменялась.

Comment: @Сергей, извините, ничем не могу помочь.